# Delete with join error

Tags: mysql, join

After executing this query:

```
 DELETE from  swimming_class as tb1 JOIN  (SELECT class_id FROM `swimming_class`
 left join swimming_school on swimming_school.school_id = swimming_class.school_id
 where swimming_school.school_name is NULL)  as temp ON temp.class_id = tb1.class_id
```

I'm getting this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as tb1 JOIN (SELECT class_id FROM swimming_class left join swimming_school on' at line 1

Comment: You can't delete from any table that you are using in the JOIN, and remove alias for tables in `DELETE` statement

Comment: @Sal00m Well, you can - you just have to get a bit clever ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are really after is the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae2ff/1)):

```
DELETE sc
FROM swimming_class sc
INNER JOIN swimming_school ss ON ss.school_id = sc.school_id
WHERE ss.school_name is NULL
```

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'swimming_class' for update in FROM clause

Comment: **@Shijin**, I updated my answer and included a demonstration.  Is that what you are after?

Comment: @Linger use `LEFT JOIN`, see original query

Comment: **@Rimas**, using `LEFT JOIN` would be the same as `INNER JOIN` in this case since `WHERE ss.school_name is NULL` is used.  If the `LEFT JOIN` did function as you would expect and pull all records from the `swimming_class` table then all records would be deleted and there would be no reason for joining to another table in the first place.  For the `LEFT JOIN` to even work you would have to use `DELETE sc FROM swimming_class sc LEFT JOIN swimming_school ss ON ss.school_id = sc.school_id AND ss.school_name is NULL`.

Comment: @Linger I mean only change `INNER` to `LEFT`, then in addition will be deleted records from `swimming_class` where `school_id` isn't in `swimming_school`, see modified query on SQL Fiddle (with added such records): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a78678/1

Comment: **@Rimas**, it is doing that anyway.  Since ***Shijin*** is specifying a `WHERE` clause and not including it in the `JOIN`, **LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN function the same here**.